# When is the request sent in request-promise?

Tags: node.js, request, request-promise

This question is about [request](https://github.com/request/request) and may also map to [request-promise](https://github.com/request/request-promise).

In the following example:

```
let myPromise = rp('http://www.google.com'); // Line 1

// do something ...

await myPromise; // Line 2
```

When is the request sent?

- Is it sent at `Line 1` when `rp(...)` is called and the returned promise is to wait for the response?
- or is it sent at `Line 2` when the returned promise is executed?

According to the following example the answer is: `rp(...)` does not send the request. It actually adds the call to the event loop which will be executed later to send the request.

```
// server.js
var http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    console.log(new Date().toISOString(), ' - Request received by server.');
    res.end('All good');
});

server.listen(3001);
```

-

```
// client.js
var rp = require('request-promise');

rp('http://localhost:3001');

console.log('something');
// Break point
```

It seems form my trial that the request is not sent if the process did not return to the event loop.

Is there is a way to make the request happen immediately and await for it later?

Is there is another library that guarantees the request to be sent before returning with a "promise to deliver the response" ?

**EDIT:**

According to @terry-lenoxx 's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49134449/when-is-the-request-sent-in-request-promise#comment85282876_49137850) request-promise actually queues the request and does not send the request immediately. Once the control returns to the event loop the queued requests will be sent.

This is useful for my case which is that I want to send multiple requests together and join each response later. This can easily be done as follows:

```
var rp = require('request-promise');

async function doSomething() {
    let req1 = rp('http://localhost:3001'); // Queue req1
    let req2 = rp('http://localhost:3001'); // Queue req2

    let response1 = await req1; // Send both req1, req2 and wait for response of req1
    let response2 = await req2; // wait for response of req2

    console.log('something');
}

doSomething();
```

I tested this behavior and it is so clear.

Comment: Promises are not executed. You called a function, it did it's thing, it returned a promise that will be resolved once the request is finished.

Comment: I understand that I didn't find a proper word. Think about creating a promise yourself to execute a function later. The function will be executed later on the next `tick` of the `process`.

Answer (score 0):

You can play about with this yourself pretty easily, put together a little app e.g.

```
var rp = require('request-promise');
var http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    console.log(new Date().toISOString(), ' - Request received by server.');
});

server.listen(3001);

console.log(new Date().toISOString(), ' - Sending request to server.');
rp('http://localhost:3001');
```

You can see the request will be received without ever waiting for the promise. The request will get executed *almost* as soon as you queue it, not exactly at the same time, since it will be sent to an I/O queue, as are all asynchronous operations in node.js.

The await line is really syntactic sugar for a promise.then(), or to put it another way, it's just creating a callback in a more readable form.

You can then add an await like below, it makes no difference to the request queuing process.

```
var rp = require('request-promise');
var http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    console.log(new Date().toISOString(), ' - Request received by server.');
    res.end('All good');
});

server.listen(3001);

async function sendRequest() {
    console.log(new Date().toISOString(), ' - Requesting..');
    let myPromise = rp('http://localhost:3001');

    console.log(new Date().toISOString(), ' - Awaiting response');
    var result = await myPromise;
    console.log(new Date().toISOString(), ' - Response received');
};

sendRequest();
```

So the answer is really *very soon* after line 1. But not exactly at the same time. And of course this means it will likely occur *after* line 2. Since it is executing on another thread.

If you want the request to happen immediately you mean send a HTTP request synchronously, this really isn't the node.js way!

Comment: Add a console log after `rp` call. You will notice that the command after rp is executed before the message is sent. You can try it with a server in another process.
`rp('http://localhost:3001');
console.log(new Date().toISOString(), ' - Request should be already sent to server.');`

Comment: Here is the output of the second example on my laptop: '2018-03-06T19:21:03.271Z  - Requesting..
2018-03-06T19:21:03.279Z  - Awaiting response
2018-03-06T19:21:03.294Z  - Request received by server.
2018-03-06T19:21:03.304Z  - Response received'

Comment: I think the console.log statements agree with the sequence I described above! I'd fully expect the command after the rp call to execute before the message is sent, since the message is processed by another thread.

Comment: Your answer above is not consistent `You can see the request will be received without ever waiting for the promise.` this is the opposite of `And of course this means it will likely occur after line 2.`

Comment: Remember we're talking about a request that's queued on another thread, so whether we wait for the promise to resolve or not doesn't affect this process in the slightest.. Line 2 will be processed very quickly after the request is queued, probably measured in microseconds, almost certainly before the actual message is sent. This is the world of asynchronous programming!

Comment: See my example of breakpoint. the request should have been sent before the breakpoint but it is not.

Comment: rp queues a request, it doesn't send it, so I would expect the breakpoint to be hit before the request goes out!